# How to show Pie chart in tableau for each row

Tags: tableau-api

I have 3 columns and I have to perform calculation using all 3 columns. And for each row I have to show Pie chart next to that. 
Creating Pie -chart for suppose 10 rows based on if-else calculation.
If anyone can help!
Thanks.

Comment: Please can you include some example data? Also your desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by:

Dragging the dimension that you want to be the single rows with their own pie chart to Rows, at the top

Then for the pie slices you drag your category dimension to colours. This is what you want to show as different colours for each pie

For the size of the slices you use the measure you want to use (your IF-ELSE calc field?). An example would be Sales

In my example, each pie is a referee, the slices are the games won/lost/drawn, and the size of the slices in the number of games that referee was in charge of

Here is a screenshot to demonstrate:

[image]

Comment: @PujaMishra How did you get on? Could you get it working? If so, please would yoou mind selecting my answer as the correct one